# Why won't my servo and ultrasonic sensor work together?

Tags: sensors, servo

I have a school project due tomorrow, and I'm planning to connect a servo motor with an ultrasonic sensor. If the distance is under 10cm, the servo motor should turn 180 degrees and will return to 0 degrees when there's no object in front of the sensor. I've tried them separately, the sensor by itself works and could read distance as usual and the servo works too. However, when I put the two code together, it just seems to cancel each other out. I don't know much about coding but pretty sure the sensor is supposed to print the distance on the serial monitor, but it just stops working, I also put some code to try and get the servo to turn, but it also doesn't work... So now I'm stuck pls help me, it's due tomorrow :(

Could it be my power source? I'm using my laptop to power it... but my friend did the same project, and it worked well using laptop as a power source, but i saw some post like this that encourages me to change power source, but isn't a laptop a huge power source? (genuinely asking)

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>
#define servopin 9
#define echoPin 4
#define trigPin 5

Servo Myservo;
int long duration;
int distance;

void setup() {
    Myservo.attach(servopin);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance = (duration * 0.034 / 2);

    if (distance < 10)
    {
        Myservo.write(180);
    }
    else
    {
        Myservo.write(0);
    }
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: you have no debugging code ... add some ... right now, you have no way to know the value of `distance`

Comment: "but isn't a laptop a huge power source? " Most USB ports are only obliged to supply 500mA.  In fact, some will go into constant current mode to protect the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on online simulator, and it works perfect!
Maybe just try another distance check like `if(distance<30)` (at least) and let's know what will happen.
*I don't think using the laptop as a power source is your problem*

Comment: I know rightt, this is very confusing. It works fine on tinkercad but it won't work in real life, I'll try your suggestion. Thanks a lot :D